# How to remove the row in a table when clicked on "delete icon" using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
 $(document).on("click", ".deleteIcon", function () {

  indexDelAgent = parseInt($(this).attr("alt").replace("Delete", ""));
  console.log("after deletion");
  console.log(indexDelAgent);

  document.getElementById("tempTable").deleteRow(indexDelAgent);

 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <!-- jQuery library -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Popper JS -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <table class="table table-bordered" id="tempTable">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>A</th>
         <th>B</th>
         <th>C</th>
         <th>D</th>
         <th>E</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <select>
               <option value="1">QQ</option>
               <option value="2">Apple</option>
               <option value="3">Orange</option>
               <option value="4">Mango </option>
            </select>
         </td>
         <td><input style="width:130px;" type="text" name="assessReason" autocomplete="off" id="assessReason4" required=""></td>
         <td><input type="number" name="assessAmount" autocomplete="off" class="amount" id="assessAmount4" required=""></td>
         <td><input type="number" name="assessPenalty" autocomplete="off" class="penalty" id="assessPenalty4" required=""></td>
         <td><i value="Delete" type="button" alt="Delete4"  class="deleteIcon fa fa-trash"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <select>
               <option value="1">QQ</option>
               <option value="2">Apple</option>
               <option value="3">Orange</option>
               <option value="4">Mango </option>
            </select>
         </td>
         <td><input style="width:130px;" type="text" name="assessReason" autocomplete="off" id="assessReason5" required=""></td>
         <td><input type="number" name="assessAmount" autocomplete="off" class="amount" id="assessAmount5" required=""></td>
         <td><input type="number" name="assessPenalty" autocomplete="off" class="penalty" id="assessPenalty5" required=""></td>
         <td><i value="Delete" type="button" alt="Delete5"  class="deleteIcon fa fa-trash"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <select>
               <option value="1">QQ</option>
               <option value="2">Apple</option>
               <option value="3">Orange</option>
               <option value="4">Mango </option>
            </select>
         </td>
         <td><input style="width:130px;" type="text" name="assessReason" autocomplete="off" id="assessReason6" required=""></td>
         <td><input type="number" name="assessAmount" autocomplete="off" class="amount" id="assessAmount6" required=""></td>
         <td><input type="number" name="assessPenalty" autocomplete="off" class="penalty" id="assessPenalty6" required=""></td>
         <td><i value="Delete" type="button" alt="Delete6" class="deleteIcon fa fa-trash"></i></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
   </body>
   
</html>
```

My table is dynamic,as It has the button to add the new row and the index gets increased with 0,1,2,3,4 after clicking on "Add new" button.(I have not shown that button here,I have only shown 3 rows here and index of table starting from 4).I need to delete the entire row when I click on delete icon of that row.I tried using the jquery by `document.getElementById("tempTable").deleteRow(indexDelAgent);` ,but it is not working. I dont want my table data to be pushed in any array.I just need to remove the entire row on clicking delete icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current code `alt` value starts with `Delete4` but there is no row at index `4` so it won't work as you expected.

To work in your current scenario you need to get an index among the remaining rows. You can get the index among the delete button simply using [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method, but you have to add `1`(to skip header) since there is no delete button inside the header.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".deleteIcon", function() {

  var indexDelAgent = $(this).index('.deleteIcon') + 1;
  console.log("after deletion");
  console.log(indexDelAgent);

  document.getElementById("tempTable").deleteRow(indexDelAgent);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Popper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="tempTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">QQ</option>
            <option value="2">Apple</option>
            <option value="3">Orange</option>
            <option value="4">Mango </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input style="width:130px;" type="text" name="assessReason" autocomplete="off" id="assessReason4" required=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="assessAmount" autocomplete="off" class="amount" id="assessAmount4" required=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="assessPenalty" autocomplete="off" class="penalty" id="assessPenalty4" required=""></td>
        <td><i value="Delete" type="button" alt="Delete4" class="deleteIcon fa fa-trash"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">QQ</option>
            <option value="2">Apple</option>
            <option value="3">Orange</option>
            <option value="4">Mango </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input style="width:130px;" type="text" name="assessReason" autocomplete="off" id="assessReason5" required=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="assessAmount" autocomplete="off" class="amount" id="assessAmount5" required=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="assessPenalty" autocomplete="off" class="penalty" id="assessPenalty5" required=""></td>
        <td><i value="Delete" type="button" alt="Delete5" class="deleteIcon fa fa-trash"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">QQ</option>
            <option value="2">Apple</option>
            <option value="3">Orange</option>
            <option value="4">Mango </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input style="width:130px;" type="text" name="assessReason" autocomplete="off" id="assessReason6" required=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="assessAmount" autocomplete="off" class="amount" id="assessAmount6" required=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="assessPenalty" autocomplete="off" class="penalty" id="assessPenalty6" required=""></td>
        <td><i value="Delete" type="button" alt="Delete6" class="deleteIcon fa fa-trash"></i></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**UPDATE :** Or far better way is to get the index of parent `tr` among all `tr`.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".deleteIcon", function() {

  var indexDelAgent = $(this).closest('tr').index('#tempTable tr');
  console.log("after deletion");
  console.log(indexDelAgent);

  document.getElementById("tempTable").deleteRow(indexDelAgent);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Popper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="tempTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">QQ</option>
            <option value="2">Apple</option>
            <option value="3">Orange</option>
            <option value="4">Mango </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input style="width:130px;" type="text" name="assessReason" autocomplete="off" id="assessReason4" required=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="assessAmount" autocomplete="off" class="amount" id="assessAmount4" required=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="assessPenalty" autocomplete="off" class="penalty" id="assessPenalty4" required=""></td>
        <td><i value="Delete" type="button" alt="Delete4" class="deleteIcon fa fa-trash"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">QQ</option>
            <option value="2">Apple</option>
            <option value="3">Orange</option>
            <option value="4">Mango </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input style="width:130px;" type="text" name="assessReason" autocomplete="off" id="assessReason5" required=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="assessAmount" autocomplete="off" class="amount" id="assessAmount5" required=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="assessPenalty" autocomplete="off" class="penalty" id="assessPenalty5" required=""></td>
        <td><i value="Delete" type="button" alt="Delete5" class="deleteIcon fa fa-trash"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">QQ</option>
            <option value="2">Apple</option>
            <option value="3">Orange</option>
            <option value="4">Mango </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input style="width:130px;" type="text" name="assessReason" autocomplete="off" id="assessReason6" required=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="assessAmount" autocomplete="off" class="amount" id="assessAmount6" required=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="assessPenalty" autocomplete="off" class="penalty" id="assessPenalty6" required=""></td>
        <td><i value="Delete" type="button" alt="Delete6" class="deleteIcon fa fa-trash"></i></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but my header gets removed when i click on delete button :(

Comment: @AshwinKarki : `indexDelAgent = parseInt($(this).index('.deleteIcon') + 1)`

Comment: @AshwinKarki : you have to add the number of headers(rows) with the index since its includes in rows

Comment: but my code worked after adding   document.getElementById("tempTable").deleteRow(index+1);  it was jsut removing header previously .Why is it happening so?

Comment: @AshwinKarki :  `deleteRow` deletes from entire rows( including from header footer, so you have to count from header )

Comment: your code was correct previously so i managed to used previous one but can u tell me $(this).index('.deleteIcon')  is the index starting from -1?

Comment: @AshwinKarki : no it's starts from 0 ... adding `1` because there is no `deleteIcon` in  header row

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery use [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) method to remove an element from DOM.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".deleteIcon", function() {
  // get the parent tr element and remove
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Popper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="tempTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">QQ</option>
            <option value="2">Apple</option>
            <option value="3">Orange</option>
            <option value="4">Mango </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input style="width:130px;" type="text" name="assessReason" autocomplete="off" id="assessReason4" required=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="assessAmount" autocomplete="off" class="amount" id="assessAmount4" required=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="assessPenalty" autocomplete="off" class="penalty" id="assessPenalty4" required=""></td>
        <td><i value="Delete" type="button" alt="Delete4" class="deleteIcon fa fa-trash"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">QQ</option>
            <option value="2">Apple</option>
            <option value="3">Orange</option>
            <option value="4">Mango </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input style="width:130px;" type="text" name="assessReason" autocomplete="off" id="assessReason5" required=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="assessAmount" autocomplete="off" class="amount" id="assessAmount5" required=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="assessPenalty" autocomplete="off" class="penalty" id="assessPenalty5" required=""></td>
        <td><i value="Delete" type="button" alt="Delete5" class="deleteIcon fa fa-trash"></i></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">QQ</option>
            <option value="2">Apple</option>
            <option value="3">Orange</option>
            <option value="4">Mango </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input style="width:130px;" type="text" name="assessReason" autocomplete="off" id="assessReason6" required=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="assessAmount" autocomplete="off" class="amount" id="assessAmount6" required=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="assessPenalty" autocomplete="off" class="penalty" id="assessPenalty6" required=""></td>
        <td><i value="Delete" type="button" alt="Delete6" class="deleteIcon fa fa-trash"></i></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the problem is that it is not removing in my code... i need to delete the row  by the value of  console.log(indexDelAgent); which is 4,5,6 there.Please can u just review it like that way?